# WebStorm solution with several Dart projects

Tags: dart, webstorm

I develop Dart with WebStorm. I have a server-project, a client-project and some shared code.

Is it possible to create a project solution, containing several Dart projects (like you can do in VisualStudio)? Or is it common to develop each project in it's own WebStorm window?

Comment: WebStorm cannot open multiple projects in one frame/window while having separate project settings for each of them (like VS does, for example) -- only one project per frame. If you still need to work with some code from multiple projects .. you can add other project folders as Additional Content Roots (`Settings/Preferences | Directories`) -- they will be listed as additional nodes in a Project View (well, actual project is just a single main Content Root) and will be treated as part of this project (no separate settings)

Comment: "actual project is just a single main Content Root". Not sure what you mean by an 'actual project'. All content roots are equal, there's no more important or less important or main content root.

Comment: @AlexanderDoroshko I meant that WebStorm project by default consists of a single Content Root; so code in additional one(s) will be treated in the same manner.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can put the project directories together in a directory and then open that directory instead.

There are also ways with project root configurations to do that with projects that are not in the same directory but I did't bother to try to understand how this exactly work.

I moved away from this setup and use different windows for different projects a while ago because I don't want to maintain project configurations. I have many Dart projects that are reusable packages that I use in many other projects.

Using one window for one Dart package seems to be the easiest setup.
I configured keyboard shortcuts (there are probably defaults anyway) for easier switching between WebStorm windows.

Comment: "I did't bother to try to understand how this exactly work". It looks easy and straight-forward to me. You open Settings (Preferences) | Directories and add Content Roots.

Comment: @AlexanderDoroshko Perhaps I should look again now, but when I started using WebStorm with Dart there were several things with content roots and included and excluded directories that caused lots of troubles. I assume that these issues are fixed since a long time, but I'm just fine with my current setup and don't miss anything.

Answer (score 3):

You can configure as many content roots as you want in one WebStorm project, see Settings (Preferences) | Directories. 
See also https://www.jetbrains.com/help/webstorm/directories.html and https://www.jetbrains.com/help/webstorm/content-root.html